# How to extract data from webpage?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get text and data from a webpage. when a page load completes inside web-browser control, I just want to extract text from the page by element id?
please help me how can i achieve this like html-agility & c#.
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Are alternative (more modern) libraries like CsQueries allowed? Also, if you just want the whole text of everything you don't need any library.

Comment: I just need few text by html id. example, <div id="getid">ID00123</div>.  so i want to know how can i get "ID00123"  from my program. I prefer to use c# windows app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `GetElementbyId` method on the `HtmlDocument` which allows you to retrieve some specific DOM element by its identifier:

```
string html = ... Read the HTML here

var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var element = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("someId");
if (element != null)
{
    string data = element.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. for one element ok, but I need to get around 10 elements from one page url.?

Comment: How about using a loop? If there's some pattern for the element ids you could simply loop through them.

Comment: I can see element-id  by viewing page source, but there are no patterns, element ids are looks completely different. can you please provide me an example.

Comment: In this case you cannot use the element `id` to retrieve the values. You should use some other information that doesn't change. For example if there are some `class` values or even the DOM structure itself. It's impossible to say without having more details about the DOM structure you are dealing with.

Comment: Example, in  c# windows app, when we enter company number, it should retrieve company information from online website and displays those information inside my c# application. Ex: page link is here.. [link](http://www.mol.gov.ae/NewMolGateway/english/Services/CompanyInfo.aspx?Code=625354)

Comment: You could use an XPath expression. For example to retrieve the company name you could use this: `string companyName = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table/tr[3]/td[1]/table/tr/td[3]").InnerHtml;`. And to retrieve the Company Classification use : `string companyClassification = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table/tr[5]/td[1]/table/tr/td[3]").InnerHtml;`.